# Using AJAX for GET data from other server on Mouse Over

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am searching for this from yesterday, Do not know, I am unable to implement, or going in wrong direction.
**My currently ajax function which is working with local server**

```
function tooltipajax(r_ID)
{
    var str  ;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('span'+ r_ID).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText ; 
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","accounteditajax.php?key=" +r_ID,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP code:

```
print("<tr bgcolor=\"#EEEEEF\">");
print("<td class='normal' id=\"serialno\" onMouseOver='tooltipajax(this.id)'>
<a class=\"tooltip\" >Serial Number <span id=\"spanserialno\" 
class=\"custom info\"></span>   </a></td>");
print("<td bgcolor = \"#FFFFFF\" ><b>$serial</b></td>\n");
print("</tr>\n");
```

How can I get data from another server?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","accounteditajax.php?key=" +r_ID,true);
```

I want to get from

```
http://iphere/filename.php
```

Comment: Does the other server allow CORS or do you have to use JSONP?

Comment: you say that this is working in your local server. What error are you getting from other servers?

Comment: server allows, I do not have idea of JSONP , So i need help for this

Comment: @sttlcu i does not gives any error,it just shows my CSS drawed for mouse over. I know It does not work with other server cause of Same domain policy, But It can be done,,,but how??

Comment: `http://iphere/filename.php` - is this your file? Or that belongs to third party server?

Comment: Fangel not file I have written that i want to access a file which is on some ip means http://ip here/filename.php  yes, that is my file which I have put on my another server

Comment: Ok. Let me rephrase my question. Do you have a control over the server with that IP?

Comment: fangel, yes I have control over ip

Comment: Then you will be able to implement JSONP. Look into JSONP via the URL I provided, and you will be able to retrieve data from the second IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you use use jQuery like so, this works.

```
function tooltip_ajax(r_ID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://iphere/filename.php?id=" + r_ID,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                $('span' + r_ID).html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

That's tested with a different server and it works.

Comment: Hey, i tried to use this code, but it does not show anything on mouse over, pls tell me How it will GET from another server?Does it needed to add GET some where??

Comment: This will NOT work with a different server. Cross-Domain Request restrictions will kick in. Whether or not these restrictions are limited to IP address is another matter, i.e. requesting from another domain on the same IP could work, or perhaps there are lighter restrictions for local domains, but AFAIK these restrictions are very strict.

Comment: yes seidr, but it works..some concept of JSONP..have u idea of that?

Comment: As far as I know, the example above is not JSONP. It is straight AJAX. Please correct my if I'm wrong, but I don't see any specification of a callback function name.

Comment: I've given you all the information you should need in my post. Sorry, but I'm not going to write the whole script for you. Experiment - you'll get there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve data from another server using AJAX, you will need to utilize JSONP. This is due to Cross-Domain restrictions on AJAX requests. To expand on this further, if you wanted to make an AJAX request from a page located at http://test1.com, to a page / script located at http://test2.com, you would not be allowed.

Check out this article for more information: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Basically, JSONP involves adding a temporary SCRIPT tag to the page, which CAN load external content. The URL for this SCRIPT tag contains data, and a callback function name. The JSONP should then respond with the data, enclosed in a call to that function. Of course, the one downside is that the target server must support JSONP requests.

One alternative is using a bridge PHP script locally, that utilizes CURL to make the request, and return the information to your page, via AJAX.

For a bit more information regarding utilizing CURL in PHP, take a look at this article: http://codular.com/curl-with-php

Comment: Look into CURL in PHP - I imagine you will be able to achieve what you're looking to do with it. Take parameters in from your AJAX request, request the target URL with CURL, and return the response to the client.

Comment: i am to implement it with AJAX, can not use CURL there

Comment: You can't implement it with straight AJAX if you are requesting from a different domain. It is only possible with JSONP, or utilizing a bridge PHP script. You can use AJAX to communicate with a PHP script on your server, which then communicates with the other server (which AJAX could not).